# group list of dataframes to another dataframe row by row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Frames is a list of dataframes with the following order and dimension:

```
[     participant activity                t  phone_accel_x  phone_accel_y  \
 0           1600        D  241598773279024       0.565436       1.049568   
 1           1600        D  241598823633028       0.502723       1.029012   
 2           1600        D  241598873987032       0.470794       1.002914   
 3           1600        D  241598924341036       0.490821       1.003417   
 4           1600        D  241598974695040       0.487980       1.033217   
 ..           ...      ...              ...            ...            ...   
 195         1600        D  241608592309883       0.677391       0.918443   
 196         1600        D  241608642663887       0.673493       0.913030   
 197         1600        D  241608693017891       0.674655       0.913004   
 198         1600        D  241608743371894       0.679319       0.914433   
 199         1600        D  241608793725898       0.676576       0.913901   
 
      phone_accel_z  phone_gyro_x  phone_gyro_y  phone_gyro_z  
 0         1.248711     -0.017212     -0.006581     -0.080116  
 1         1.197390     -0.121311      0.050491     -0.109368  
 2         1.224439     -0.324749     -0.007777     -0.148947  
 3         1.234429     -0.290535     -0.105310     -0.151757  
 4         1.223829     -0.100016     -0.093174     -0.112706  
 ..             ...           ...           ...           ...  
 195       1.250941     -0.008502      0.028063      0.019072  
 196       1.260808     -0.004811      0.027223      0.024403  
 197       1.266306      0.000024      0.022763      0.023875  
 198       1.258972      0.003954      0.012599      0.021185  
 199       1.259517     -0.006841      0.007218      0.012923  
 
 [200 rows x 9 columns],
      participant activity                t  phone_accel_x  phone_accel_y  \
 50          1600        D  241601290979316       0.667534       0.907823   
 51          1600        D  241601341333320       0.659705       0.917594   
 52          1600        D  241601391687324       0.650291       0.908096   
 53          1600        D  241601442041328       0.641641       0.901728   
 54          1600        D  241601492395332       0.659827       0.899954   
 ..           ...      ...              ...            ...            ...   
 245         1600        D  241611110023497       0.673400       0.913214   
 246         1600        D  241611160377501       0.677467       0.912210   
 247         1600        D  241611210731505       0.681255       0.905807   
 248         1600        D  241611261085509       0.670614       0.904358   
 249         1600        D  241611311439513       0.668775       0.909658   
 
      phone_accel_z  phone_gyro_x  phone_gyro_y  phone_gyro_z  
 50        1.277606     -0.031145     -0.012867     -0.057229  
 51        1.272129     -0.039413      0.005489     -0.044188  
 52        1.290153     -0.056169      0.004972     -0.065202  
 53        1.274855     -0.044967     -0.010766     -0.078963  
 54        1.290040     -0.046148     -0.010928     -0.075745  
 ..             ...           ...           ...           ...  
 245       1.246544     -0.006509      0.009480      0.009705  
 246       1.250491     -0.012193      0.010935      0.008721  
 247       1.256942     -0.006915      0.017657      0.008312  
 248       1.264303     -0.007985      0.019806      0.001612  
 249       1.265652      0.002644      0.007558      0.004734  
 
 [200 rows x 9 columns], etc
```

All the dataframes are of the same dimension 200 rows x 9 columns and the len(frames) is 91999. I want to create a new dataframe that contains the values of all the 200 rows of every dataframe in one row but only for the columns phone_accel_x, phone_accel_y, phone_accel_z, phone_gyro_x, phone_gyro_y, phone_gyro_z and activity. The values of each dataframe will be added as new row, so the new dataframe will be of dimension 91999 rows x 1201 columns (200 x 6 + 1).

```
sensors_frames = []
for i in range(0, len(frames)):
        t = frames[i][['phone_accel_x', 'phone_accel_y', 'phone_accel_z', 
                   'phone_gyro_x', 'phone_gyro_y', 'phone_gyro_z', 'activity']].values
        sensors_frames.append(t)
```

i am trying something like this, but i am having difficulties in stacking the values of each column in a single row and continue in a new line for the next dataframe. The list sensors_frames will be converted to a dataframe afterwards.

Any ideas to make it happen with pandas library?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want an output of 200 rows and 643993 columns?

Comment: no, 91999 rows and 1201 columns.

Comment: OK, and you have only a unique value in activity?

Comment: exactly. in every row the last column will be a single value of the corresponding activity.

Comment: i want to take all the values of the specific columns (200 values in total for each column) and stack them all together in 1 row. every row contains all the 200 values of each column, 200 * 6 = 1200 columns + 1 column for the activity. The next dataframe of 200's values will be the next row in exactly the same manner. hope that helps. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pandas-based solution - I timed it on my machine and took around 2 minutes to run.

```
import pandas as pd

# simulate input data
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "participant": [1600] * 200,
        "activity": ["D"] * 200,
        "t": [241598773279024] * 200,
        "phone_accel_x": [1.049568] * 200,
        "phone_accel_y": [1.049568] * 200,
        "phone_accel_z": [1.248711] * 200,
        "phone_gyro_x": [-0.017212] * 200,
        "phone_gyro_y": [-0.006581] * 200,
        "phone_gyro_z": [-0.080116] * 200,
    }
)

columns = [
    "phone_accel_x",
    "phone_accel_y",
    "phone_accel_z",
    "phone_gyro_x",
    "phone_gyro_y",
    "phone_gyro_z",
]

frames = [df] * 91_999

# suggested solution
df_frames = pd.concat(frames, axis=0, ignore_index=True)

df_frames["step"] = df_frames.index // 200

reshaped = df_frames.groupby(["step", "activity"]).apply(
    lambda grp: pd.DataFrame(
        grp[columns].values.reshape(1, -1),
        columns=[f"{col}_{i}" for i in range(200) for col in columns],
    )
).reset_index()
```

Comment: thanks so much for your time! i will try it out. the only thing that confuses me a bit is, why in the df dataframe you took the multiplication of only the first value? i mean the values are already in groups of 200 in the list frames.

Comment: You are welcome - I did the multiplication to simulate the "frames" data but yes definitely you don't need to do so on your end given you have the actual data